# Using the word "worthwhile" alone

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

If I want to describe something in a sentence like:

> We believe that doing X is worthwhile.

In particular I mean can I use worthwhile without following it with a noun like `endeavor` or something else.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary has this example in "worthwhile": The time and expense involved in keeping up to date with all the changes *has been* worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. *Worthwhile*, like most adjectives (not all) can be used predicatively as well as attributively.